# Why do command lines now have two hyphens (--) behind each parameter? Where did it originate, why not use a single hyphen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-core, .net-core

.NET Core, and several javascript libraries seem to now use two hyphens for each command line parameter.

Why is this happening now all of a sudden?

Does it have any (historic) meaning?

Why not use just a single hyphen? (what convention are we aligning to? xNix?)

Comment: *Behind* the parameter? Do you have an example? FWIW there is a convention to have single-letter options (`-r`) with a single dash, full-word options with two (`--recursive`). This allows you to batch flags together: `rm -rf` instead of `rm -r -f`.

Comment: I think behind means before in this context as in your example @Thilo

Comment: And then there is `--` *behind* some parameters to separate parameter groups. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376

Comment: The introduction of the --longname syntax is a GNU extension to POSIX standards: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html. These are both *ancient* conventions and not new at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [What's the difference betwen the single dash and double dash flags on shell commands?](https://serverfault.com/questions/387935/whats-the-difference-betwen-the-single-dash-and-double-dash-flags-on-shell-comm) (ServerFault)

> A single hyphen can be followed by multiple single-character flags. A
>   double hyphen prefixes a single, multicharacter option.
>
> Consider this example:
>
> `tar -czf` In this example, `-czf` specifies three single-character flags:
>   `c`, `z`, and `f`.
>
> Now consider another example:
>
> `tar --exclude` In this case, `--exclude` specifies a single,
>   multicharacter option named exclude. The double hyphen disambiguates
>   the command-line argument, ensuring that tar interprets it as exclude
>   rather than a combination of `e`, `x`, `c`, `l`, `u`, `d`, and `e`